# Json input parameter to SQL stored procedure from ADF

Tags: json, parameters, azure-data-factory

In ADF, I am trying to pass JSON variable to azure sql stored procedure. The json value is below.

Input

```
{
    "storedProcedureName": "[dbo].[SP_INSERT_BLOBFILELIST]",
    "storedProcedureParameters": {
        "BlobFileName": {
            "value": [
                {
                    "itemName": "fileone_20211103055924081.zip",
                    "lastModified": "2021-11-03T09:59:30Z",
                    "size": 77894,
                    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "DefaultIntegrationRuntime (East US 2)",
                    "executionDuration": 0,
                    "durationInQueue": {
                        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 1
                    },
                    "billingReference": {
                        "activityType": "PipelineActivity",
                        "billableDuration": [
                            {
                                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                                "unit": "Hours"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "filetwo_20211104050042529.zip",
                    "lastModified": "2021-11-04T09:01:15Z",
                    "size": 77893,
```

My stored procedure is below.

```
alter  procedure dbo.SP_INSERT_BLOBFILELIST (@BlobFileName nVarchar(max))
as
begin
INsert into dbo.BlobFileList
select getdate(),* From openjson(@BlobFileName,N'$.value')
with (itemName varchar(500) N'$.itemName', 
lastModified datetime N'$.lastModified')
end
```

The ADF is saying error "Execution fail against sql server. Sql error number: 13609. Error Message: JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'S' is found at position 0."

Can anyone please help.

Comment: I am also facing similar issue. The output from my GetMetadata activity is like:               
 {"structure": [{"name": "Id","type": "String"},{"name": "Salary","type": "Decimal"}]}.  Passing this as @jsonSchema parameter to a SP as @activity('GetSourceStructure').output.structure. Stored Proc is defined like:           
 ;WITH tableStruct
  AS (SELECT
    [key] AS fieldOrder,
    JSON_VALUE(value, 'strict $.name') AS fieldName,
    JSON_VALUE(value, 'strict $.type') AS fieldType
  FROM OPENJSON(@jsonSchema, '$.value'))

Comment: were you able to resolve this ??

Comment: The input to my stored procedure activity looks like this:                                                                 
 {
 "storedProcedureName": "[dbo].[create_tbl]",
 "storedProcedureParameters": {
  "jsonSchema": {
   "value": [{
     "name": "Id",
     "type": "String"
    },
    {
     "name": "Salary",
     "type": "Decimal"
    }
   ],
   "type": "String"
  }
 }
}

Comment: Srivasan - check if this helps:                                                                                                      SELECT
  @fileName = value 
FROM
  OPENJSON(@json, N'lax $')
WHERE [key] = 'itemName'

Comment: I was able to resolve my issue by doing following changes - (1) converted the Json input parameter as "string" - @string(activity('GetSourceStructure').output.structure).            (2) changed the stored procedure as below :                                                                 
 SELECT
     ,j1.[key] as fieldOrder
            ,j2.name as fieldName
     ,j2.type as fieldType
INTO table
FROM OPENJSON(@jsonSchema) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) 
WITH ( name varchar(100) , type varchar(100)) j2

Comment: You need to also do it similarly, in your case - see below:                                     
 DECLARE @jsonSchema nvarchar(max) = N'[{
 "itemName": "fileone_20211103055924081.zip",
 "lastModified": "2021-11-03T09:59:30Z",
 "size": 77894,
 "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "DefaultIntegrationRuntime (East US 2)",
 "executionDuration": 0
}]'
SELECT
        j2.itemName as itemName
    ,j2.lastModified as lastModDttm
--INTO table1
FROM OPENJSON(@jsonSchema) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) 
WITH
( itemName varchar(100) ,
  lastModified varchar(100)
) j2